# How to check if a string containing a number and a letter is in between two values in Java?

Tags: java

I'm writing a code for Data Validation and Testing Data and it has stages with certain restrictions and will only move on to the next stage if the user meets the restrictions. For one of them, the user has to enter a number between 5 and 500.

Eg:

- If input is 155, it moves on to the next stage
- If input is -12, it loops and stays on this stage

I want to make it so that if the user enters a String like "65A", it moves on because 65 is in between 5 and 500. How do I go about making the condition statement?

Comment: What if the input is "8A0"? Is it 80 or 8?

Comment: Please show what have you done so far and maybe that could allow us to help you out. From what I understand, it seems like you want to remove all non-numeric characters from your input.

Comment: `int v = Integer.parseInt("65A".replaceAll("\\D+", ""));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you just want to remove all non-numeric from your input, should be as easy as

```
    const lowerBound = 5;
    const upperBound = 500;

    String str = "65A";

    int number = Integer.parseInt(str.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));

    System.out.println(number);

    if (number >= lowerBound && number <= upperBound) {
        // all good
    } else {
        // no good
    }
```

Comment: I'm still a newbie to java, can you please explain what [^\\d] stands for?

Comment: It's a [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) that looks for everything that is not a number, then the replaceAll function removes the chars

Comment: If I want to keep the negative numbers negative so that the program loops, do I just add a "-" to the end of ^\\d? It seems to work when I test it but I wanted to check if that's the right process for future programs

Comment: For negative numbers it's mentioned on the answer below by Arvind Kumar Avinash, you can use `^[-]?\\d+`

Answer (score 1):

Use the regex `^[-]?\\d+` to retrieve the integer from the beginning of the input. Note that `[-]?` in the regex, makes `-` optional.

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[-]?\\d+");
        boolean valid;
        int num;
        do {
            valid = true;
            System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
            input = kb.nextLine();

            // Process the input only if it starts with an int
            if (input.matches("[-]?\\d+.*")) {
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    try {
                        num = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group());
                        if (num < 5 || num > 500) {
                            System.out.println("Error: valid range is from 5 to 500. Please try again.");
                            valid = false;
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                        }
                        System.out.println("Number is: " + num);
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        if (valid) {
                            System.out.println("Error: invalid input. Please try again.");
                            valid = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error: invalid input. Please try again.");
                valid = false;
            }
        } while (!valid);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter a number: 65a
Number is: 65
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter a number: 5
Number is: 5
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter a number: a
Error: invalid input. Please try again.
Enter a number: 65a
Number is: 65
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter a number: a65
Error: invalid input. Please try again.
Enter a number: 65a
Number is: 65
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter a number: -65a
Error: valid range is from 5 to 500. Please try again.
Enter a number: 65a
Number is: 65
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Enter a number: 600
Error: valid range is from 5 to 500. Please try again.
Enter a number: 65a
Number is: 65
```

Check the following links to learn more about Java regex API:

1. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html
2. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple and clear code

```
String sampleString = "65a";
String numberOnly=sampleString .replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

if(numberOnly > 5 && numberOnly < 500){
 System.out.println("Welcome to the next stage");
}
else{
 System.out.println("Try again");
}
```